# How to do connection pooling on CXF endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, cxf, connection-pooling

I'm using camel 2.16.0 and cxf 3.1.2.

I have an cxf endpoint as below in my camel context .. (TEST_ENDPOINT is an actual endpoint)

```
<to uri="cxf://{{TEST_ENDPOINT}}?dataFormat=payload&amp;loggingFeatureEnabled=true" />
```

I wanted to limit the number of HTTP connections to TEST_ENDPOINT, Tried below but it doesn't help..

```
<bean id="http" class="org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent">
        <property name="camelContext" ref="sendSMSContext_rest" />
        <property name="httpConnectionManager" ref="myHttpConnectionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myHttpConnectionManager"
        class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager">

        <property name="params" ref="myHttpConnectionManagerParams" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myHttpConnectionManagerParams"
        class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams">
        <property name="maxTotalConnections" value="5" />
    </bean>
```

When i do a load test, i can see 200+ ESTABLISHED connection, though maxTotalConnections is 5 !!
any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to configure this on camel-cxf (CXF) instead of the HTTP component.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @ClausIbsen. you mean i have to configure on this ? <to uri="cxf://{{TEST_ENDPOINT}}?dataFormat=payload&amp;loggingF‌​eatureEnabled=true" />
but how to do this in my context xml ?

Comment: Read the CXF and camel-cxf documentation. As CXF has its own way of configuring threading on the bus or something like that.